# This is undefined in function inside class function

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have the following js code snippet(slightly simplified from the original) and I cannot figure out why I am getting a `TypeError: this is undefined` for the line `this.onError(event.error.message)`. I understand that `this` is not valid in the scope but I can't wrap my head around as to why.

How can I solve this without having to pass `onError` to the `initialize()` method?

```
class Class1{

    constructor(props) {
        this.class2 = Class2(props.publicKey);
        this.onError = props.onError;
    }

    //initialize the form
    initialize() {

        //add error handler
        this.class2.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
            if (event.error) {
                this.onError(event.error.message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is specific to enclosing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `this` context to the variable and use it in callback function:

```
initialize() {
    var that = this;
    //add error handler
    this.class2.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
        if (event.error) {
            that.onError(event.error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this before but used it inside the callback function...Thank you, worked ver well.